# deployd mongodb connection error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, deployd

I'm learning Angular js and trying to run deployd server. Followed http://terraltech.com/how-to-setup-deployd-on-ubuntu-server/ steps mentioned here.

When I try to add a row from deployd dashboard am getting below error as a response

```
{"message":"Database connection error","status":400}
```

Here is my production.js server configuration.

```
var deployd = require('deployd');

var server = deployd({
  port: process.env.PORT || 5000,
    env: 'production',
    db: {
      host: 'SAMLP15070001',
    port: 27017,
    name: 'deployd',
    credentials: {
      username: 'deployd',
    password: 'deployd'

    }

    }

});

server.listen();

server.on('listening', function() {
  console.log("Server is listening");

});

server.on('error', function(err) {
  console.error(err);
  process.nextTick(function() { // Give the server a chance to return an error
    process.exit();
  });

});
```

Here is my mongo information which I configured in production.js

```
> getHostName( )
SAMLP15070001
> show dbs;
admin     0.078GB
local     0.078GB
test      0.078GB
```

I'm not sure whey is my deployd db is not getting displayed here.

Can someone help  me in resolving this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

From your mongo you have to execute the following commands:

```
mongo shell

use admin

db.addUser( { user: "deployd", pwd: "deployd", roles: [ "userAdminAnyDatabase" ] } )

use deployd

db.addUser( { user: "deployd", pwd: "deployd", roles: [ "readWrite", "dbAdmin" ] } )
```

Comment: But I don't see the command `addUser` present in my mongo version. My version is 3.0.6

Comment: Here is the error which am getting when I try the command mentioned by you 

> `db.addUser( { user: "deployd", pwd: "deployd", roles: [ "userAdminAnyDatabase" ] } )`

`2015-09-18T11:35:18.054+0530 E QUERY    TypeError: Property 'addUser' of object admin is not a function
    at (shell):1:4`

Comment: I tried that one and below is the error
 `db.createUser( { user: "deployd", pwd: "deployd", roles: [ "userAdminAnyDatabase" ] } )
2015-09-18T11:37:30.218+0530 E QUERY    Error: couldn't add user: User "deployd@admin" already exists
    at Error (<anonymous>)`

which means user is already present and db is also present but its not listing when I do `show dbs`

Comment: try to login as a `deployd` user and see if it works

Comment: I tried and here is the result
`db.auth("deployd", "deployd")
1
> show dbs
admin     0.078GB
local     0.078GB
test      0.078GB`